# How to translate sed "s" command from double to single quotes

Tags: sed, dockerfile

My problem is that I have this command:

```sh
sed -i -E 's/((^|\s)PATH=)([^\$]*)$/\1${PATH:-\3}/g' /foo
```

and as far as I use it with single quotes it works fine but now I need to use it with double-quotes (because Dockerfile doesn't like single ones) and when I try to translate it to:

```sh
"s/((^|\s)PATH=)([^\$]*)$/\1${PATH:-\3}/g"
```

I get this error: `` unknown option to `s' ``. So I read that I can try to replace the separators and I tried with `@`:

```sh
"s@((^|\s)PATH=)([^\$]*)$@\1${PATH:-\3}@g"
```

But with that I get: `` unterminated `s' command ``. I also tried to replace with `;`:

```sh
"s;((^|\s)PATH=)([^\$]*)$;\1${PATH:-\3};g"
```

and that "succeeded" but the end result was different to what I expected. Any ideas on how can I translate this properly to use it with doubled-quotes?

Comment: escape all the dollar signs and backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't! You can easily translate it to a string with backslashes and no quotes:

```
$ printf "%q\n" 's/((^|\s)PATH=)([^\$]*)$/\1${PATH:-\3}/g'
s/\(\(\^\|\\s\)PATH=\)\(\[\^\\\$\]\*\)\$/\\1\$\{PATH:-\\3\}/g

$ sed -E s/\(\(\^\|\\s\)PATH=\)\(\[\^\\\$\]\*\)\$/\\1\$\{PATH:-\\3\}/g
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) escaping backslashes and dollar signs does the work, this worked for me:

```sh
"s/((^|\\s)PATH=)([^\\\$]*)\$/\\1\${PATH:-\\3}/g"
```

Thanks!

Comment: This step is needed because q double-quoted string is subject to shell variable expansion.  Single-quoted strings are not.